# iOS save to storage issue

Tags: codenameone

I've an issue while trying to save an image to the Storage in iOS. Image is downloaded but not saved.

The code is:

```
        Form hi = new Form("Toolbar", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    TreeModel tm = new TreeModel() {
        @Override
        public Vector getChildren(Object parent) {
            String[] files;
            if (parent == null) {
                files = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots();
                return new Vector<Object>(Arrays.asList(files));
            } else {
                try {
                    files = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().listFiles((String) parent);
                } catch (IOException err) {
                    Log.e(err);
                    files = new String[0];
                }
            }
            String p = (String) parent;
            Vector result = new Vector();
            for (String s : files) {
                result.add(p + s);
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
            return !FileSystemStorage.getInstance().isDirectory((String) node);
        }
    };
    Command tree = new Command("Show tree") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Form treeForm = new Form("Tree", new BorderLayout());
            Tree t = new Tree(tm) {
                @Override
                protected String childToDisplayLabel(Object child) {
                    String n = (String) child;
                    int pos = n.lastIndexOf("/");
                    if (pos < 0) {
                        return n;
                    }
                    return n.substring(pos);
                }
            };
            treeForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, t);
            Command back = new Command("Back") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    hi.showBack();
                }
            };
            Button backButton = new Button(back);
            treeForm.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, backButton);
            treeForm.show();
        }

    };
    hi.getToolbar().addCommandToOverflowMenu(tree);
    EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(hi.getWidth(), hi.getWidth() / 5, 0xffff0000), true);
    String photoURL = "https://awoiaf.westeros.org/images/thumb/9/93/AGameOfThrones.jpg/400px-AGameOfThrones.jpg";
    StringBuilder fsPath = new StringBuilder(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath());
    fsPath.append("400px-AGameOfThrones.jpg");
    URLImage background = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, fsPath.toString(), photoURL);
    background.fetch();
    Style stitle = hi.getToolbar().getTitleComponent().getUnselectedStyle();
    stitle.setBgImage(background);
    stitle.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
    stitle.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
    stitle.setPaddingTop(15);
    SpanButton credit = new SpanButton("Link");
    credit.addActionListener((e) -> Display.getInstance().execute("https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Game_of_Thrones"));
    hi.add(new SpanLabel("A")).
            add(new Label("B", "Heading")).
            add(credit);

    ComponentAnimation title = hi.getToolbar().getTitleComponent().createStyleAnimation("Title", 200);
    hi.getAnimationManager().onTitleScrollAnimation(title);
    hi.show();
```

Which was taken from https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/URLImage.html

The tree is only to see if the image was saved in the Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `Storage` & `FileSystemStorage` which are very different things see [this](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-use-storage-file-system-sql.html).

You can use storage which is a flat set of "files" and that's what `URLImage.createToStorage` does. But then you need to use the `Storage` API to work with that and it might not be visible in the `FileSystemStorage` API.

Alternatively you might be looking for `URLImage.createToFileSystem()`.